# How can I resize and show a cropped image with patches using matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

When I run the following code it show a clipped image, however the image showed still has the original size of the image, I want that it shows only the size of the new cropped part. How can I scale it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook


with cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.png') as image_file:
    image = plt.imread(image_file)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(image)
patch = patches.Circle((260, 200), radius=200, transform=ax.transData)
im.set_clip_path(patch)

ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
`
```

Comment: Set the x and ylim